# WebDriver: ChromeDriver attempting to reach http://localhost/session on initialization and failing

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The full error message is:

```
 Test(s) failed. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59662/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

The line in my code where this is happening simply instances a new ChromeDriver instance:

```
CurrentDriver = new ChromeDriver(section["chromedriverfolder"]);
```

So my question is... why does a new ChromeDriver invokes the /session URL, and what could be causing it to fail?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same error using Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v2.22 and Chrome v52.0.2743.116 m running on TeamCity 9.x. I was able to fix the problem by rolling back the version of Chrome running on the TeamCity agents to v51.

When examining the agent executing the test, there is a popup with error: "Chrome Automation extension has crashed. Click this balloon to reload the extension."

It seems like a bug with the latest version of Chrome and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver, but as of yet this is the only lead I've [found](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1080#c51)

EDIT: The link to the [ChromeDriver issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1453)

EDIT2: The link to the [resolution](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1389#c25)

Comment: You roll back Chrome itself? Not Chromedriver?

Comment: Since earlier versions of ChromeDriver only [support Chrome through v50](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/notes.txt), it seems easier to roll back just Chrome rather than Chrome and ChromeDriver :)

Comment: Can I ask you were you could find an old version of Chrome for Windows?

Comment: Right [here](http://www.chrome-portable.com/index.php/google-chrome-offline-installer)

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks @PallWilleaux!
I've also tried updating ChromeDriver to 2.23, still the same problem. Only solution was to downgrade Chrome.

Comment: Interesting. jpsfs, how did you downgrade Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer where ChromeDriver invokes the /session URL, but not to the second part why it is timing out. Please see if it can provide some lead to the debug process to find out the failure :
When we call new ChromeDriver()
It creates RemoteWebDriver in the constructor :

```
super(new DriverCommandExecutor(service), capabilities);
```

which ultimately goes to :

```
public RemoteWebDriver(CommandExecutor executor, Capabilities desiredCapabilities,
      Capabilities requiredCapabilities) {
```

In this method we do startClient which basically does nothing in this particular case

After startClient we do :

```
startSession(desiredCapabilities, requiredCapabilities);
```

This method issues the request /session in the following line :

```
Response response = execute(DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters);
```

The DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION is set as newSession which is mapped to post /session in the Command Codec

```
defineCommand(NEW_SESSION, post("/session"));
```