# Selenium WebDriverException using ChromeDriver v2.23 and Chrome v52

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The latest version of Chrome v52.0.2743.116 seems to have affected our tests which use Selenium with Chrome.  We have previously updated the chromedriver version through the Selenium NuGet package if there has been an update to Chrome.  The latests driver mentions being compatible with v52.

The call to construct the ChromeDriver (OpenQA.Selenium,Chrome) fails as shown

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:9220/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
```

The stack trace is:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory)
at InternalPortal.IntegrationTests.Helpers.WebBrowser.get_Current() in C:\GoAgent\pipelines\WHSLE_IntFacing_CustPortal_Commit\Source\InternalPortal.IntegrationTests\Helpers\WebBrowser.cs:line 59
```

Our code at line 59 looks like:

```
ScenarioContext.Current["webDriverChrome"] = new ChromeDriver(path);
```

This passes the path to where the chromedriver.exe file is.

These tests worked previously until the version of Chrome updated from v51 to v52.  It was working on ChromeDriver version 2.19 (Selenium NuGet 2.19.0.0), so we upgraded to 2.23 (Selenium NuGet 2.23.0.1) which shows as working with v52 but we get the exception shown.

The tests are running through a Thoughtworks GO agent, triggered by a pipeline job if that helps.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: I believe you should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834808/webdriver-chromedriver-attempting-to-reach-http-localhost-session-on-initiali/38854469#38854469 Best,
jpsfs